# Syntax of font-variation-settings is altered in browser

Tags: css, netlify

I'm currently playing around with variable fonts.
I have implemented a working variable font and want to change the weight of a `<h3>` on hover.

Using `font-variation-settings: 'wght' 200;` and `font-variation-settings: 'wght' 500;` on hover works perfectly fine locally, but as soon as I push it to the master branch on Github and it gets published via Netlify, it stops working. Checking it with the inspector in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox* it is revealed that the single quotes get removed, so it's just `font-variation-settings: wght 200`. I double checked the uploaded .css-file and it's in there correctly.

[Screenshot from inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2JqJ.png)

If I add the single quotes in the inspector manually, it starts to work on the live page.

Every source I read about variable fonts uses this syntax of font-variation-settings (I tried it with double quotes, too), so I don't know why it gets lost.

I implemented the font like this:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Variable';
 src:url("_assets/fonts/variable.ttf") format("truetype-variations");
 font-weight: 200;
 font-style: normal;
 font-stretch: normal;
}
```

The CSS is this

```
.inner h3 {
 font-variation-settings: 'wght' 200;
}

.inner:hover h3 {
 font-variation-settings: 'wght' 500;
}
```

The font is displayed correctly on the live page, just the weight change does not work.

*I know that variable fonts are not fully supported by Firefox.

Comment: Try the "wght" in the css, if the single quotes removes. Do you use github where you push your code? After you push it, the single quotes are not in the pushed code?

Comment: I tried the double quotes with the same result. I'm pushing to Github (added that to the question, thanks) and after the push the quotes are in the pushed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Netlify's asset optimization system caused the issue. Turning off "Minify CSS" under "Build & deploy" in the settings solved it.
Netlify's great support helped me figuring it out.